# How do you determine a shapefile's charset?

Tags: shapefile, dbf

Is there a way to determine the charset used for a given shapefile?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Trial and error. Try to open the .dbf file with Ms Excel or with OpenOffice using different setting until you get everything right.

Look at this post for more clues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319095/how-do-i-determine-the-character-set-of-a-string

Comment: If nothing is known about the encoding, it's worthwhile to try latin1 or UTF-8 first.

Comment: I have opened the .dbf in Ms Excel and the characters show up normally. How can I see which encoding Excel is using/detecting?  So that I can set it in QGIS...

Answer (score 14):

There are two ways for programs to determinate the character set for a shapefile.

- The first is the codepage file *.cpg.
- The second is the codepage info, which can be inside the dbase file. The specification could be found at http://www.clicketyclick.dk/databases/xbase/format/dbf.html#DBF_STRUCT

Comment: +1 That link to a dBase file format page is great.  However, AFAIK, codepages were never included in the dBase III format.  The reference there is to a FoxPro extension of the format, which suggests not all .dbf files are going to have codepage info in them (or, if they do, it might be a result of garbage bytes appearing in a free area of the header).  But if you can dig this information out, it's still a good start for a trial-and-error search.  BTW, welcome to our site!

Comment: Some python dbf libraries can read the codepage if information is there.

Answer (score 5):

The `file` utility is able to guess the encoding of a text file. Use `ogr2ogr` for a conversion that preserves the original encoding **if there is no `.cpg` file**:

```
ogr2ogr -f CSV file.csv file.dbf
file file.csv
```

Example output:

```
file.csv: ISO-8859 text
```

I have tested it with two of the most frequent encodings, UTF-8 and latin1. Works out of the box in Ubuntu, not sure about OS X. I'm not aware of a `file` utility on Windows.

**NOTE**: As soon as there is a corresponding `.cpg` file that indicates the encoding, `ogr2ogr` will honor it and the output will be in UTF-8. But if the CSV output looks right, you know that the information in the `.cpg` file is accurate.

Answer (score 3):

Another table for converting 29th byte of *.dbf to code page:
http://webhelp.esri.com/arcpad/8.0/referenceguide/index.htm#locales/task_code.htm