# Read shapefile in GeoPandas using pyarrow gives encoding error

Tags: python, geopandas

I am trying to read a shapefile with German letters (e.g.ß) with the following script:

```
import geopandas as gpd

df = gpd.read_file(
    r"path/to/file.shp",
    engine="pyogrio",
    use_arrow = True

)
```

However, I get an encoding error, and I did try to specify it with `encoding = "utf-8"`, but I alsow tried `"latin"` and `"ISO-8859-1"`, but none worked.
This is the error message:

```
ArrowException: Unknown error: Wrapping Chausseestra�e failed
```

How can I fix it?

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I believe that the fix is to define the encoding to match with the one used in the shapefile. Unfortunately it may be hard to find what encoding the shapefile is using. Similar problem in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65990086/geopandas-encodings-for-never-seen-before-characters.

Comment: What if you try `encoding = "cp1250"` ?

Comment: @Taras I did try your solution, but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: Can you please check the encoding of your shapefile?

Comment: How can I check my encoding? I have multiple files.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/12218/99589

Comment: What about ISO-8859-2 or cp1250 encodings ?

Comment: Both the encoding specified by an optional `.cpg` file and any encoding details present in the `.dbf` LDID header block are considered.

Comment: I'd try to add a .cpg text file to the shapefile (so same stem as .shp file, but suffix .cpg) with just the following tekst in it: `CP1252`. In the past it solved some issues for me with the text `maïs` (= dutch) in shapefiles.

Comment: If `CP1252` doesn't work, try replacing the `CP1252` with some alternative encodings in the .cpg file, e.g. `CP1250`, `ISO-8859-1`, `Windows-28591`,...