# How to encode shapefiles from LATIN1 to UTF-8?

Tags: shapefile, encoding

Is there a way to encode shapefiles from LATIN1 to UTF-8?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do this with QGIS. First load your shapefiles then `save as` and coding select dropdown menu utf-8 and then save your file.

Comment: **Word of caution**: for this solution to work qgis must be started in a LATIN1/ISO-8859-1 environment when you open the input shapefile or it won't read it correctly. If you are working in an UTF8 enviroment the conversion might fail silently, corrupting the data, depending on the data in the shapefile.
BTW, most OSes now default to UTF8.

Comment: Note that in some situations it may not work, I had this kind of issues: (http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/UTF-8-no-more-td4647456.html)

Comment: I am trying to save single shape file from system to utf-8 but it is not working. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/219092/how-to-change-shapefile-data-source-encoding-directly

Answer (score 29):

Assuming that you are on Linux and have access to a recent version of [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/) you can try the following (from this [post](http://www.mail-archive.com/gdal-dev@lists.osgeo.org/msg12322.html)) :

```
 export SHAPE_ENCODING="ISO-8859-1"
 ogr2ogr output.shp input -lco ENCODING=UTF-8
```

Note: LATIN1 should work too instead of ISO-8859-1.

In Windows, do NOT set the `SHAPE_ENCODING`, `ogr2ogr` does not recognize `ISO-8859-1`, nor `LATIN1`.

Comment: Just to clarify, “recent” here seems to mean 1.9.x. I tried this with 1.8.1 and it did not work, tried again with 1.9.1 and it did.

Comment: Didn't work for me on Windows.

Comment: Got it to work in Windows, have updated the answer.

Comment: Do you know if I can look-up the list of valid values for `SHAPE_ENCODING` somewhere?

Comment: @JJD They are the same used by iconv: http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/

Comment: Maybe on Windows one could use: SET SHAPE_ENCODING="ISO-8859-1" in the command-line before calling ogr2ogr? Just a hunch.

Comment: @Rauni: I did, omitting the double quotes and it worked. Some time ago, but this still appears the only way to convince ogr2ogr that the input .dbf has LATIN1/WIN1252/ISO-8859-1 encoding. LATIN1 and WIN1252 did not work. Use ISO-8859-1

Answer (score 5):

If my understanding of Shapefiles is correct, the part that is encoding-sensitive is the attribute database contained in the DBF file.

Here is an answer that helped me solve this issue using LibreOffice Calc/Base:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/3663/17998

It has the additional benefit that you can open the DBF file using a distinct character set and thus find out what the current encoding actually is.