# Chinese encoding problem in ogr2ogr from DXF file to GeoJSON?

Tags: gdal, geojson, ogr2ogr, dxf

I have a `dxf` format file named `test.dxf` which has some Chinese characters inside. I tried to transform it to GeoJSON file using `ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON test.geojson test.dxf` and returned GeoJSON showing unrecognizable characters like this:

`comp:甯岀背绉戯紙鍖椾含锛夊尰鑽鎶€鏈夐檺鍏徃"`

I also tried with `ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON test.geojson test.dxf ENCODING='UTF-8'` but it doesn't work out.

How can I get the result correctly?

Related reference:

[Converting shapefile from Shift_JIS to UTF-8 when the usual methods fail](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142358/converting-shapefile-from-shift-jis-to-utf-8-when-the-usual-methods-fail)

Comment: Do you mean that those characters are not using a correct Chinese character set?

Comment: No, the output of transformed Chinese characters are unrecognizable messy characters. I think maybe need to set encoding configure to `ogr2ogr`.

Comment: Have you read https://www.gdal.org/drv_dxf.html and what it says about character encoding?

Comment: Yes, I just read it, please give me some advices. I have read a question's answer which says I may re-save `test.dxf` file with encoding utf-8 using `qgis`, but I hope to use command like `ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON test.geojson test.dxf ENCODING='UTF-8'` to transform, i'm not sure if it's possible.

Comment: https://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html

Comment: Ogr2ogr is reading and writing data through the drivers. You have .dxf as input so the source data must be understandable for GDAL as documented in https://www.gdal.org/drv_dxf.html. You must check if you have correct codepage in ($DWGCODEPAGE). If you do not have you will fail. You may fail even if you have is correct because dxf driver is obviously most tested with ANSI 1252. Can you offer any small dxf for test data? You used an option `ENCODING='UTF-8'`, where is it documented?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92140/discussion-between-ahbon-and-user30184).

Answer (score 1):

you need add DXF file encoding config，this command: "--config DXF_ENCODING".
eg:

```
ogr2ogr --config DXF_ENCODING "UTF-8" -f GeoJSON C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\Test.geojson C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\Test.dxf
```

[reference resources](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/5626)

Comment: Hi Xi and welcome on GIS.Srackexchange, could you add some details to your answers. links can die after some time so it's prefered to add some text to your code

Comment: This is the correct answer in the code

Comment: I know but this code snippet is only providing immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made

Comment: ok，I have corrected it