# Creating shapefile with UTF-8 encoded attributes with ogr2ogr

Tags: shapefile, ogr2ogr, dbf, utf-8

I'm using GDAL/OGR's `ogr2ogr` command line tool to export data from a PostGIS-enabled PostgreSQL database to various GIS file formats, Shapefile amongst them. To create a shapefile with the default encoding (ISO8859-1 a.k.a. `latin1`, see [Which character encoding is used by the DBF file in shapefiles?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3529/which-character-encoding-is-used-by-the-dbf-file-in-shapefiles/3663#3663)), I'm using a command line like this:

```bsh
ogr2ogr \
    -f 'Esri Shapefile' \
    $OUTPUT_PATH \
    -t_srs $OUT_SRS \
    "PG:dbname=${DB_NAME} user=${DB_USERNAME} password=${DB_PASSWORD} schemas=${SCHEMA_NAME}"
```

But in my data, there may be features with arbitrary languages and scripts in the attribute values. I'd like to preserve these values and thus think that the `*.dbf` file of the exported Shapefile should be UTF-8 encoded. (The attribute names are guaranteed to be within 7-bit ASCII.)

**How can I get `ogr2ogr` to write a UTF-8 encoded `*.dbf` file when exporting to Shapefile?** [The documentation](http://gdal.org/drv_shapefile.html) of the GDAL/OGR "ESRI Shapefile / DBF" driver is explicitly ambigous (sic!) about the `ENCODING` option in the "Layer Creation Options":

> The default value is "LDID/87". It is not clear what other values may be appropriate.

And will the used encoding be indicated in the `*.dbf` file itself or in an accompanying `*.cpg` file? (I guess the latter, as UTF-8 probably isn't per se a valid (dBASE DBMS) DBF encoding.) If the latter, will `ogr2ogr` create the `*.cpg` file or do I have to create it manually?

Comment: If this works `ogr2ogr output.shp input -lco ENCODING=UTF-8` then your question is a duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15912/how-to-encode-shapefiles-from-latin1-to-utf-8.

Comment: That works. Thanks, @user30184! But while the answer seems to be the same and the questions certainly overlap, I don't agree that the questions are duplicates of each other. (Just from the question title, mine is a bit more general: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/15912/51574 just asks for a Shapefile-to-Shapefile conversion, while my question doesn't care (too much) about the input source and focuses on the output.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> How can I get `ogr2ogr` to write a UTF-8 encoded `*.dbf` file when exporting to Shapefile?

Similar to [How to encode shapefiles from LATIN1 to UTF-8?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15912/how-to-encode-shapefiles-from-latin1-to-utf-8/15915#15915), this is possible with `-lco ENCODING=UTF-8`. So for my case

```bash
ogr2ogr \
    -f 'Esri Shapefile' \
    $OUTPUT_PATH \
    -t_srs $OUT_SRS \
    "PG:dbname=${DB_NAME} user=${DB_USERNAME} password=${DB_PASSWORD} schemas=${SCHEMA_NAME}" \
    -lco ENCODING=UTF-8
```

> And will the used encoding be indicated in the `*.dbf` file itself or in an accompanying `*.cpg` file? (I guess the latter, as UTF-8 probably isn't per se a valid (dBASE DBMS) DBF encoding.)

The latter, indeed: In `*.cpg` files (one per database table), each just having the content

```
UTF-8
```

> If the latter, will `ogr2ogr` create the `*.cpg` file or do I have to create it manually?

`ogr2ogr` will create the `*.cpg` files for you.

Comment: FYI, `-lco ENCODING=UTF-8` with still throw a ERROR during the COPY phase if the source data contains an invalid character.

Comment: @TheoF, an invalid character in which codec?