# Viewing French characters in QGIS Attribute table

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, encoding, internationalization, france

I have a shapefile *'output'* with encoding windows-1252 IANA encoding. The attributes of a column contain some French characters, which appear as `?`.

Even I tried changing the encoding of QGIS itself to Français, the special French characters were not visible in the attribute table. How to solve this using QGIS?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does `Save As` to UTF-8 work for this case as well? [How to encode shapefiles from LATIN1 to UTF-8?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15912/how-to-encode-shapefiles-from-latin1-to-utf-8)

Comment: No luck with UTF-8.

Comment: Do you know how the file was created (by which software, from which input) ? Maybe the input file was already wrongly encoded.

Comment: If your computer OS is in french, try "system option" for encoding. It works in spanish OS and their special characters

Comment: Didnt work.....