# Converting encoding using ogr2ogr on macOS

Tags: ogr, ogr2ogr, mac

I'm trying to convert my shapefiles from `ISO-8859-10`, also known as latin6 using ogr2ogr on my Mac like this ([learned from here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/15915/9073)):

```
export SHAPE_ENCODING="latin6"
ogr2ogr file_utf8.shp file.shp -lco ENCODING=UTF-8
```

But, nothing is converted. Well, a new shapefile is created but it still has the same old encoding. I've tried with `SHAPE_ENCODING="ISO-8859-10"` and still no happy result. Then I tried just a random word like SHAPE_ENCODING="blablabla" but then ogr2ogr gives me an error:

```
Failed to create field name 'FIELD1' : cannot convert to blablabla
```

So it seems like `ogr2ogr` understands the latin6 encoding but then doesn't do the job for me. Maybe this is a macOS only problem?

If I do the conversion to GeoJSON with `SHAPE_ENCODING="latin6"` the GeoJSON file gets recoded to UTF-8 fine:

```
export SHAPE_ENCODING="latin6"
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON file_utf8.geojson file.shp
```

Then I can convert the GeoJSON file back to Shape again:

```
export SHAPE_ENCODING="utf-8"
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" file_utf8.shp file_utf8.geojson
```

Is there a way of converting encoding without going through the GeoJSON conversion process?

Comment: Created a batch script using the geojson method: https://gist.github.com/oskarlin/51e3758ce1f1d89440324eb0a564a65f

Comment: I have been using GML as an interim format and iconv for changing the character set. Your batch is at least as good.

Comment: Create the text file named as your shape file and cpg extension `file.cpg` and put one line of text `8859-10` into it. This will help GDAL to get right encoding of your shape file.

Comment: In my source files containing the latin6 encoding the CPG-files had this: "ISO 88591" in the CPG file. When I change it to "885910" it now works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an answer based on Dimitry Baryshnikovs comment to my question. If there isn't a `CPG` file with the same name as the shape file, create one and add the line `885910`.

In my case I already had CPG files but they were all wrong (consisted of the line `ISO 88591`) which caused the big problem. After altering my CPG files to `885910` I had no problem running the line of code:

```
ogr2ogr file_utf8.shp file.shp -lco ENCODING=UTF-8
```