# How did QGIS fix a shapefile's character encoding, and can I do this on the command line with ogr2ogr?

Tags: qgis, mysql, ogr2ogr, encoding

**Solved**: I'm not sure why, but it works fine if I specify `--config SHAPE_ENCODING "ISO-8859-1"` in my ogr2ogr command. For whatever reason, this allowed ogr2ogr to go from the original TigerLine shapefile, as-is, directly into a MySQL database. My final ogr2ogr instruction, in full:

```
ogr2ogr --config SHAPE_ENCODING "ISO-8859-1" -f "MySql" MySql:"usa_basemap,host=127.0.0.1,user=myUser,password=myPass,port=3306" -lco engine=MYISAM "C:/path/to/data/tl_2012_us_county.shp" -nln county -nlt "geometry" -s_srs EPSG:4269 -t_srs EPSG:3857
```

---

**Background**: I was finally able to use ogr2ogr to import the [TigerLine 2012 USA Counties shapefile](http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2012/COUNTY/tl_2012_us_county.zip) into MySQL, but only after using QGIS to save the shapefile with a new encoding value (UTF-8).

I'm wondering: What can I do differently, right inside the commandline with ogr2ogr, to avoid having to involved QGIS in the workflow? (Nothing against QGIS, it's just that I want to be able to automate this..)

---

**Here's what I did *before* involving QGIS**:

1) Changed the MySQL max_allowed_packet size as is warned might be necessary on the [OGR MySQL driver page](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_mysql.html).

In MySQL Workbench, I set the new parameter value [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8062996/786131):

```
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=1073741824;
```

2) Next, I tried to import it into MySQL with ogr2ogr like this:

```
ogr2ogr -f "MySql" MySql:"basemap,host=127.0.0.1,user=myUser,password=myPass,port=3306" -lco engine=MYISAM "C:/path/to/data/tl_2012_us_county.shp" -nln county -nlt "geometry" -s_srs EPSG:4269 -t_srs EPSG:3857
```

But that bombs with an error that spills outside of the buffer, it ends as shown below, note the appearance of the special chars, which are lost.

```
[....hugely....truncated....console....output....]
322122,-7366573.8710948359 2062754.2910927597))',1) , '72', '045', '01804502', '
72045', 'Comer�o', 'Comer�o Municipio', '13', 'H1', 'G4020', '490', '41980', 'A'
,       73557129,         319735, '+18.2250402', '-066.2202984')
```

It's worth noting that after hitting this brick wall and Googling around, I tried the tips suggested by Mateusz Łoskot [in this discussion](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.gdal.devel/29864); to restate the salient portion:

> *Windows Command Prompt can work with UTF-8 characters if you change codepage to UTF-8:
>
> 0) Open new prompt (cmd.exe)
>
> 1) Change font to Lucida Concole
>
> 3) chcp 65001*

But this didn't overcome the obstacle.

Finally, wondering if QGIS could help, I used QGIS to export the shapefile, specifying UTF-8 as the character encoding, *then* the ogr2ogr command I provided above worked. Bingo. Now I have "Comerío Municipio" in my database..

..but what gives?

So my question: **Is QGIS doing something I can add to my ogr2ogr instruction that automatically resolves the special characters issues I encountered so I can automate this task in the future and not have to manually involve QGIS?**

Comment: You should mention which QGIS/GDAL version you are using. QGIS 1.7.3 did the encoding correct, 1.8.0 is buggy, and 1.9.0 has the chance to do it right again.

Comment: That's fair---I'm using Q 1.8. However, QGIS was the solution, not the problem, and I was hoping to accomplish whatever Q did directly in ogr2ogr. But @steko's answer down there looks promising.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting from the **[GDAL documentation for the Esri Shapefile driver](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_shapefile.html)**:

> An attempt is made to read the LDID/codepage setting from the .dbf
>   file and use it to translate string fields to UTF-8 on read, and back
>   when writing. LDID "87 / 0x57" is treated as ISO8859_1 which may not
>   be appropriate. The SHAPE_ENCODING configuration option may be used to
>   override the encoding interpretation of the shapefile with any
>   encoding supported by CPLRecode or to "" to avoid any recoding.
>   (Recoding support is new for GDAL/OGR 1.9.0)

Depending on which GDAL/OGR version you are using, `ogr2ogr` may be trying to translate your data to UTF-8 or not doing nothing at all.

So you would do either:

```
ogr2ogr --config SHAPE_ENCODING "UTF-8" -f "MySql" MySql:"basemap,host=127.0.0.1,user=myUser,password=myPass,port=3306" -lco engine=MYISAM "C:/path/to/data/tl_2012_us_county.shp" -nln county -nlt "geometry" -s_srs EPSG:4269 -t_srs EPSG:3857
```

or

```
ogr2ogr --config SHAPE_ENCODING "" -f "MySql" MySql:"basemap,host=127.0.0.1,user=myUser,password=myPass,port=3306" -lco engine=MYISAM "C:/path/to/data/tl_2012_us_county.shp" -nln county -nlt "geometry" -s_srs EPSG:4269 -t_srs EPSG:3857
```

Finally, check that your MySQL database is using UTF-8 and not Latin-1.

Comment: Ok man, you led me to the right place so you get the green check mark. Although--somewhat counter-intuitively--the `config` option that ultimately worked was this: `--config SHAPE_ENCODING "ISO-8859-1"` Note that it doesn't have an `=` between the key and the value, also that it didn't work with UTF-8, but with ISO-8859-1. But thanks a ton for your help,  I'll post the complete solution in the question. Maybe someday, someone will take an interest and describe why I needed to force-feed the ISO-8859-1 encoding. :)

Comment: @elrobis Feel free to read the metadata that came with that shapefile =) I'm sure whoever made it will appreciate that. It's the .shp.xml in the zip. Have a close look at the very top, what does `encoding` say? That's the encoding of that shapefile. You need to import to a db with that encoding, otherwise as seen in the gdal docs, it will try to force it to UTF-8 which will lose special chars that UTF-8 encoding doesn't handle.

Comment: Some shapefile providers are really generous and include a .cpj file which has, in plain text, the shapefile encoding that the attributes are stored in. You can always open that in a text editor to see it. See http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/3663/1297

Comment: @steko Your first option is what's causing the error, the second option could fix it by not translating from the source encoding of `"ISO-8859-1"` to `"UTF-8"`. GDAL would try to find it automatically and use the existing encoding, but to be safe, the OP has specified the exact encoding needed.

Comment: @SaultDon, thanks for the extra insight here. Just for clarification, does the "encoding" in the XML header truly describe the shapefile itself, or is that just a coincidence? Or said differently, can I count on that? If nothing else it'd always be worth a try! This was definitely an odd one to crack, and I'm glad to have some more ammo for the future.

Comment: @elrobis, You're right to be suspicious, it could be specific to the xml, but if in doubt the data source provider can either verify the encoding or point you in the right direction to where that info is recorded.