# geoserver export shapefile chinese problem

Tags: geoserver

I'm trying to export shpfile from a postgis to shape-zip .
 So i issue the standard GetFeature request with shape-zip as format to geoserver. 
The shpfile which i get Charset is ISO-8859-1  so the chinese is '????' .
 How can i change the iso-8859-1 to utf-8?

postgis charset is utf-8 and geoserver global charset is utf-8

[image]

Comment: [See this answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3529/which-character-encoding-is-used-by-the-dbf-file-in-shapefiles/3663#3663). It has a couple of solutions that may work for you, including a .cpg file or saving the DBF in OpenOffice Calc.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your GET request: format_options=CHARSET:UTF-8

Comment: It's clear why this answer is right - it sets charset. That's it. There is no explanation needed, at least for GIS developers.