# Problem in importing shapefile to Postgis with postgis Shapefile manager

Tags: postgis, shapefile, import, encoding

i have a problem with importing my shapefile to postgreSQL, it's a poroblem with the encoding, here's the screenshot:
[image: Import failed]

i tried to change encodingin "options" buti get this message:

"Failed in pgui_exec(): ERREUR:  séquence d'octets invalide pour l'encodage « UTF8 » : 0xe3 0xa9 0x72

Shapefile import failed.
"

Do i have to change the encoding in arcgis?and how?

thnks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you start importing in the Shapefile-loader click on the "options"-button and there replace "UTF8" with the correct encoding.

Comment: I did it alread, but i get this error "Failed in pgui_exec(): ERREUR: séquence d'octets invalide pour l'encodage « UTF8 » : 0xe3 0xa9 0x72

Shapefile import failed"

Comment: Did you load the Shapefile in a desktop gis like QGIS before and checked if the characters (franch "accents" etc.) are displayed correctly in the attribute table?

Comment: if you don't know the encoding of the shapefile you could also try to import it with the shapefile loader using some common encodings like CP1252, IBM850 or ISO8859-15.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer to [Which character encoding is used by the DBF file in shapefiles?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3529/which-character-encoding-is-used-by-the-dbf-file-in-shapefiles/3663#3663):

> To change the encoding of a DBF open it with OpenOffice Calc.. choose
>   SaveAs... click the "Filter options" in the bottom left and press
>   save. You can then define the encoding to convert the text contents
>   into.

As you may already know, feature attributes of your Shapefiles are stored in a DBF file. Go to the folder where the Shapefile is located and you see the DBF file. You can get OpenOffice Calc (or better yet, LibreOffice Calc from [here](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-fresh/)).

Concerning field names of your Shapefile, from the same answer:

> Attention: All this only applies to the data, not the column names.
>   You should really only use ASCII in the column names of a DBF if you
>   want the file to be openable with other programs.