# How to change encoding options for a shp file in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, internationalization, turkey

After creating a shp file with attributes containing Turkish characters like ş,ç,ü.., Upon exporting it as another shp file , shp file having problem on displaying those characters, Is there any way in ArcGIS to change encoding option like in QGIS. I can change system encoding from UTF-8 to windows 1254 in QGIS and I have no problem on displays. But how do I do it in ArcGIS???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a post to a more general question ([Which character encoding is used by the DBF file in shapefiles?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3529/which-character-encoding-is-used-by-the-dbf-file-in-shapefiles)), but maybe one of the answers is helpful for you:

"ArcGIS and Geopublisher, AtlasStyler and Geoserver started to extend the standard to define the encoding. For ArcGIS, Geopublisher and AtlasStyler SLD Editor, just create a .cpg file (with the same basename as the other Shapefiles) and fill it with the name of the encoding.

e.g. create a myshape.cpg with a texteditor and insert 5 characters "UTF-8" and save it. If you then open the Shapefile in ArcGIS or Geopublisher or AtlasStyler, they will read the textual contents of the DBF in that charset." [answered Nov 19 '10 at 9:45 by alfonx]

Comment: What a great hack! It's extremely useful, thank you for sharing! :) It worked well for French caracters.