# Export attribute table to Excel readable format

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, attribute-table, export, excel

I want to save some attribute tables in a file format that Excel can read. Currently I'm using the tool Table to dBASE in Modelbuilder, but when I open the files in Excel it shows some errors in characters like "ç", "à", "õ". For example, what should appear like "Vila Chã" actually appear like "Vila ChÒ"

I need a format that accepts this type of characters correctly. How can I work around this situation? The solution should be a geoprocessing tool that can be used in a model, like "Table to Excel"

I've installed the tool "Table to Excel" and this is the error I'm getting:

[image]

There's some problem with encoding, but how can I solve this?

Answer (score 6):

Use ["Table To Excel Tool"](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Table_To_Excel/001200000054000000/) instead. It outputs the attribute table directly to xls format.

If it s not available with 10.0, download it from:

http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=cbb7b0ea4c014dd8bc2832f9be1e2d03

Comment: I think that tool only comes in 10.2 and higher, so he will have to download it

Comment: Where do I put the extracted files from zip? And how I use the tool? It's giving me errors when I use the tool, maybe I'm not doing it properly

Comment: @AndM extract the files and browse to its location via catalog window in ArcMap or Arccatalog.

Comment: It's what I'm doing. I've updated the question with a print of the errors that I'm obtaining.

Comment: I have tested it with unicode characters and works fine. What is the source of your data (e.g. shapefile)? if it is shapefile what is the encoding?

Comment: It's shapefile, how do I know the encoding?

Comment: create .cfg file with the same name of your shapefile and fill it with "UTF-8". see [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137753/how-to-change-encoding-options-for-a-shp-file-in-arcgis) for more information

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30306/discussion-between-andm-and-farid-cher).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to a tool called table 2 excel.  It should do what you want and it works within a model

https://geonet.esri.com/thread/97530

http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/08/10/working-with-microsoft-excel-in-arcgis-desktop/