# Import UTF-8 encoded Shapefiles into SQL Server?

Tags: shapefile, sql-server, ogr2ogr

I am trying to load a shapefile to SQL Server, using ogr2ogr and Shape2SQL tools. The shapefile uses UTF-8 encoding, specified in a .cpg file, and confirmed when opening the file with QGIS.

However, as this post explains:
[Which character encoding is used by the DBF file in shapefiles?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3529/which-character-encoding-is-used-by-the-dbf-file-in-shapefiles) The .cpg file only applies for data, not column names. So both tools (ogr2ogr and shape2sql) fail when reading the file due to that reason.

I have tried converting the .dbf file to various formats (from plain ascii, to utf8 without bom, to utf8) using Notepad++ but with no results.

Is there any semi-automatic way to convert the column names to their latin equivalent, or force either of these programs to read column names in utf8?

Comment: What's your target: Postgres, MySQL, ...?

Comment: @underdark sql server 2008 r2

Answer (score 2):

1. make sure your table uses UTF-8 encoding
2. this command works for me in windows:

   ogr2ogr -f "MySQL" MYSQL:"db_name,host=localhost,user=root,password=root,port=3306" -nln "table" -a_srs "EPSG:4326" c:\a.shp  -lco ENGINE=MyISAM