# Reading files with Japanese filenames with GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas, error, internationalization, nameerror

I'm trying to read all shapefiles in a folder using this script:

```
import glob
import geopandas as gpd

infolder = r'E:/folder/test_input'
shapefiles = glob.iglob(infolder+'/*.shp')
gdfs = [gpd.read_file(file) for file in shapefiles]
```

All of the shapefiles have Chinese/Japanese characters in their names and I am getting this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 8: invalid start byte
```

It works fine with shapefiles of English names. How do I solve this issue?

EDIT: I am also getting this error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'crs_wkt' referenced before assignment
```

I'm not sure why as all shapefiles including English name ones are of the same coordinate system epsg:6668

Comment: This seems to be a codepage issue with Python, which is orthagonal to EPSG codes.

Comment: You might need to encode file before you gpd.read_file(file) - your r'folder' doesn't affect the file name,  and doesn't need the r. Try gpd.read_file(file.encode('utf-8')).

Comment: @wingnut thanks for the reply. I tried what you suggested "gdfs = [gpd.read_file(file.encode('utf-8')) for file in shapefiles]" but it's returning the error "TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object". Any suggestions?

Comment: Actually,  that makes sense. Exactly where do you get the error? Which statement?

Comment: See this advice. It's for Arc, but may solve the problem. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3529/which-character-encoding-is-used-by-the-dbf-file-in-shapefiles

Comment: Getting it exactly on "gdfs = [gpd.read_file(file.encode('utf-8')) for file in shapefiles]"

Comment: `fiona` is not able to determine the encoding of your file (and it is not UTF-8). If you know the encoding, you can pass it to `read_file` as `gpd.read_file(file, encoding="utf-8")`. I don't think `file.encode` will work on shapefile with multiple input files. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48305400/cant-open-shape-file-with-geopandas

Comment: Very strangely, when I ran my original code without assigning or changing any encoding on 1 shapefile at a time it worked for all of them.. but it just didn't work when trying to iterate through all of them. Not really sure why. Thanks for pointing to that advice @wingnut, not sure I fully understand it yet, but will try to.

Comment: Thank you @martinfleis for the suggestion also, will try that in the future